# Почему '$match' может не влиять на скорость выполнения запроса с 'aggregate', `lookup` или `unwind`?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Пытаюсь ускорить в [redash](https://redash.io/help/data-sources/querying/mongodb/) запрос, примерно такой:

```
{
    "collection": "TaskItems",
    "aggregate": [
        {
            "$unwind": "$Results"
        },
        {
            "$match": {
                "Results.IsSucceed": true
            }
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                "ResultItemId": "$Results.ResultItemId", 
                "Id": "$Id",
                "Date": "$StartedAt"
            }  
        },
        {
            "$lookup": {
                "from": "Tasks",
                "localField": "Id",
                "foreignField": "Id",
                "as": "Task"
            }
        },
        {
            "$unwind": "$Task"
        },
        {
            "$match": {
                "Task.Owner.Id": {
                    "$nin": [
                        "...", 
                        "...", 
                        "..."
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": "$Date",
                "count": {
                    "$sum": 1
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Решил просто добавить ограничение на период первым пунктом в `aggregate`, обычно это решает проблему:

```
"$match": {
    "$and": [   
        {"StartedAt": {"$gte": {"$humanTime": "{{From}}"}}},
        {"StartedAt": {"$lte": {"$humanTime": "{{To}}"}}}
    ]
}
```

Но в случае этого запроса время выполнения осталось прежним. С чем это может быть связано и видны ли другие способы ускорить этот запрос?

Возможно `$lookup`/`$unwind` возвращает документы из другой коллекции, пропуская условие из `$match`. Хотя это противоречило бы документации [Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/)

Comment: наверное, потому что сначала `unwind`, потом фильтр

Comment: Тоже об этом сразу подумал, поменял местами - так же медленно.

Может этот запрос можно вообще без `unwind` переписать? Мне просто фантазии не хватает, чтобы понять как

Comment: что выводит доп параметр`{ explain: true }`?

Comment: Вывод с `{ explain: true }`: https://gist.github.com/banyrule/b3f35a1129d268d4db80bc45e10d254a

Comment: Прочитайте план сверху вниз. Первым идет `$cursor`, в нем ваше условие, которое обычно помогает. Смотрим глубже, `queryPlanner`: в нем `indexFilterSet: false` - индекс не используется, `winningPlan`: `COLLSCAN` - полный проход. Добавьте индекс на StartedAt. [Мана 1](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-plans/), [мана 2](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/), [мана 3](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/analyze-query-plan/). Но вообще я не эксперт в этом вопросе.

Comment: С добавление индекса `COLLSCAN` сменился на `IXSCAN`, хотя запрос всё так же не проходит. 

Можете оформить комментарий в виде ответа

Comment: `хотя запрос всё так же не проходит` - не понял, вы решили проблему через добавление индекс?

Comment: Нет, не решил. Но я думаю дело уже в большом объёме коллекции и lookup'ах

Comment: Скорее всего добавление `view` коллекции должно помочь